# change the div box b.color rotationally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just want to change the background color of the each div box rotationally and when one div box is changed to background white, then, rest of the boxes remains it original color, i mean not white, see the code http://jsfiddle.net/zrfQn/36/. Any idea how to achieve this? Right now, this below code is changes all the boxes to white at a time, this is not the expecting

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
    <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
    $("div.container div").each(function(event){
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        $("div.container div").not(this).css("background-color", "none"); 
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrfQn/37/)
you can check in the interval the index of the div which you want to change, and then remove the background from all other classes

```js
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {

  $("div.container div").each(function(i, event) {
    if (i == index)
      $(this).addClass("white");
    else
      $(this).removeClass('white');
  });
  index++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 121px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 89px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.one {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 34px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.two {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 34px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.three {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 59px;
  position: relative;
  top: -43px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
}
.four {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 59px;
  position: relative;
  top: -132px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.selectedtab {
  background-color: white;
}
.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

if you want this to happen infinite times, use modulo operator see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrfQn/39/)

Comment: Hi, It should not do just once, it should run through continuously. Could you please help me on that..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) for this rotation like this:

```js
var i = 0,
    $tabs = $("div.container div");

setInterval(function () {
    $tabs.removeClass('selectedtab').eq(i++ % $tabs.length).addClass('selectedtab');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
    width: 121px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top:130px;
    margin-left:130px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 89px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.one {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 34px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.two {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 34px;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.three {
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-left: 59px;
    position: relative;
    top: -43px;
    width: 30%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: brown;
}
.four {
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-left: 59px;
    position: relative;
    top: -132px;
    width: 30%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: darkred;
}
.selectedtab {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
    <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly? `i++ % $tabs.length` part?